# WooCommerce - Add product category below product price

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm a PHP novice putting a site together for a relative. I'm having a hard time with one niggling issue.

I would like to display the product category below the product title and have it link to the product category (it's necessary for this particular product catalog). I would also like this to be a link, which when clicked takes you to that particular product category.

I have found online some source code below which works to a degree - however, it does not link to the product category and I am completely stumped as to how to get it to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_product_cat', 25);
 function add_product_cat() {
 global $product;
 $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
 $count = count($product_cats);
 foreach($product_cats as $key => $cat)
 {
     echo
    '<span class="category-title">
 <span class= "category-title_'.$cat->slug.'">'.$cat->name.' </span></span>';
   if($key < ($count-1))
     {
         echo ' ';
     }
     else
     {
         echo ' ';
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_product_cat', 25);
 function add_product_cat() {
 global $product;
 $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
 $count = count($product_cats);
 foreach($product_cats as $key => $cat)
 {
     echo
    '<span class="category-title">
        <a href="'. get_term_link( $cat->term_id ) .'"><span class= "category-title_'.$cat->slug.'">'.$cat->name.' </span></a>
        </span>';
   if($key < ($count-1))
     {
         echo ' ';
     }
     else
     {
         echo ' ';
     }
 }
}
```

Updated Part

```
<a href="'. get_term_link( $cat->ID ) .'"><span class= "category-title_'.$cat->slug.'">'.$cat->name.' </span></a>
```

added link to that particular term.

Comment: Thank you for replying Abdul. I tried something similar to that earlier and it didn't work. I've tried porting your code in however I am met with an error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string. It points to the line containing:  `<a href="'. get_term_link( $cat->ID ) .'"><span class= "category-title_'.$cat->slug.'">'.$cat->name.' </span></a>`

Comment: answer is updated. try with "term_id" instead of just "ID" in get_term_link.

Comment: awesome. it works. thank you so much for helping me. You've really got me out of a jam! THANKS!